# Make stdout and stderr be buffered by the same buffer

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, glibc

Is it possible to force glibc to use the same buffer for `stdout` and `stderr`?

If I `tee` the both outputs:

```
./tests/tests 2>&1 | tee log
```

I get mixed messages (i.e. messages are ordered inside `stdout` and `stderr` but not with respect to each other). I can turn off the buffering:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./tests/tests 2>&1 | tee log
```

But it cause large slowdown (I'm pushing hundreds of MB of log). Is it possible to do have buffering but have it shared between `stdout` and `stderr`? FD `1` and `2` points to the same output (as in example).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain in what context you want to make the buffer the same, but in a C program, the author can use the `setbuf()` family of library functions to give `stderr` and `stdout` the same buffer.

Just usig the shell to invoke other programs, I don't think you can do this, for the reasons implied by the `setbuf` family of functions: the implementations of `FILE *stderr` and `FILE *stdout` have a per instance piece of memory (the buffer). If a program doesn't get written in a specific way, a way that sets the buffer to be the same piece of memory for `stdout` and `stderr`, then the shell can't make a program do that common buffering.

Comment: My reading of `setbuf(3)` is that they wouldn't share the state of buffer - only contents - hence bad things would happened (tm). However it is not stated explicitly.

Comment: I can read setbuf(3) and setvbuf(3) the same way you do.  Now that you bring it up, I imagine that bad things would happen, that the equivalent of data race conditions occur. Maybe if you just did `stderr = stdout;` ?