# systemd & python logging

Tags: systemd, python, systemd-journald

I wrote a simple python3 skript and want to make a service from it. Here are the two files

```
#!/bin/python3
while True:
     print('True')
```

Systemd Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=True Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=python3 /root/print_true.py
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is starting but i cant see the output anywhere. Not in `journalctl -u true-service.service`, not in `systemctl status true-service` and not in `syslog`. I want to have it only in journal but how can i accomplish that? I cant seem to find a working answer.

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513993/5132 again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `systemd-cat` to accomplish that, pipe the output to it.

**Test it:**

`echo "hello world" | systemd-cat -ttrue-service`

**List the output:**

`journalctl -t true-service`

**Change your service unit:**

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/print_true.py | /usr/bin/systemd-cat -ttrue-service`